# What is the python setup() `provides` argument for, using setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools

When you create a package using setuptools, you can do:

```
setup(
...
provides=[a list of stuff]
...
)
```

What is it for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, nevermind, I got it: it for you to list external modules that you embed in your code and that there for you "provide".

Comment: If you got this from reading the documentation, it might help to include the appropriate link or reference.  Maybe this?  http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#relationships-between-distributions-and-packages